# Warning: require_once(D:xampp/htdocs/\wedding-management-php\admin\include\Helper.php)

Tags: php

Error:

```
Warning: require_once(D:xampp/htdocs/\wedding-management-php\admin\include\Helper.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\harshi\admin\include\init.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:xampp/htdocs/\wedding-management-php\admin\include\Helper.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\xampp\htdocs\harshi\admin\include\init.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\harshi\index.php(1): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\harshi\admin\include\init.php on line 8
```

I am new to php.

I tried deleting the file and make a new folder in `xampp/htdocs/` then too facing the same issue.

Comment: Make sure your paths are correct. From what I'm seeing your xammp is installed at the `C`-root, yet you are trying to include files from you `D`-root

Answer (score -2):

As I see, you got the wrong path to the file, it can be your problem:

D:xampp/htdocs`/\`wedding-management-php\admin\include\Helper.php

Try to change \ in your this path.

Although, as @DarkBee mentioned, you got path to xampp in D: disk, but seemp it installed on C:

Comment: how to do it ??